# Merge more than 1 SELECT statements in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any other way to combine more than 2 `SELECT` statements in a MySQL query other than using `UNION` or `UNION ALL`? I already tried using `UNION` and `UNION ALL` but my **query loads too slowly**. This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    'AVAILABLE' AS STATUS, 
    count(id_status) as BIL
FROM 
    book_records AS b, book_class AS c
WHERE 
    b.id_book = c.id_book AND 
    id_status IN ( 1 ) AND class_desc =  'NOVEL'
UNION
SELECT 
    'WAITING' AS STATUS, 
     count(id_status) as BIL
FROM 
    book_records AS b, book_class AS c
WHERE 
    b.id_book = c.id_book AND 
    id_status IN ( 2,3,5 ) AND 
    class_desc =  'NOVEL'
UNION
SELECT 
    'DAMAGED' AS STATUS, 
    count(id_status) as BIL
FROM 
    book_records AS b, book_class AS c
WHERE 
    b.id_book = c.id_book AND 
    id_status NOT IN ( 1,2,3,5 ) AND 
    class_desc =  'NOVEL'
```

Result:

```
STATUS      BIL
----------------
AVAILABLE   5
WAITING     25
DAMAGED     0
```

Can anyone give me an idea how to solve issue?

Comment: Please post the output of the explain statement here so we can see which part of the union is taking so long. It might not be the union. Use explain.....

Comment: That query would give you an error, because you have two tables, b and c. But in the WHERE clause, you have p and k. And you have two other columns with no prefixes.

Comment: When I combine this 3 select statement using Union @ Union All it take more than 18 second to load the result. I try change my query by using 'CASE' statement but when 'count(id_status)' is 0, the 'STATUS' for that id will not come out.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Mixed up with my other query. I already fix my query above. But can anyone suggest me a solution for this problem?

Comment: What is the table prefix for id_status and class_desc? b or c?

Comment: b for id_status and c for class_desc

Comment: The query looks fine for the most part. What you can do is make sure you have an INDEX for id_book, id_status and class_desc to make it go faster.

Comment: I try put an INDEX but it load more slow than before. Huhuhu...what else I should do?

Comment: That's impossible. If you have an INDEX for those three fields, it must go faster. Make sure the two tables have an index for those relevant fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result with one pass through the table, rather than three passes at it.

My personal preference would be to return a slightly different resultset, a single row with three aggregates:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(b.id_status IN ( 1 ))) AS `AVAILABLE`
     , SUM(IF(b.id_status IN ( 2,3,5 ))) AS `WAITING`
     , SUM(IF(b.id_status NOT IN ( 1,2,3,5 ))) AS `DAMAGED`
  FROM book_records b
  JOIN book_class c
    ON c.id_book = p.id_book
   AND c.class_desc = 'NOVEL'
 WHERE b.id_status IS NOT NULL
```

To transform that result to the three rows your current query returns, we can generate the three rows you want returned (inline view aliased as s), and then match the counts from the query above (as inline view aliased as t).  We'll do a CROSS JOIN (there's only one row from t), and use a CASE expression to pick out which count to return on which row...

```
SELECT s.status
     , CASE WHEN s.status = 'AVAILABLE' THEN t.count_available
            WHEN s.status = 'WAITING'   THEN t.count_waiting
            WHEN s.status = 'DAMAGED'   THEN t.count_damaged
       END AS BIL
  FROM ( SELECT 'AVAILABLE' AS status, 1 AS seq
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'WAITING', 2
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'DAMAGED', 3
       ) s
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IF(b.id_status IN ( 1 ))),0) AS count_available
              , IFNULL(SUM(IF(b.id_status IN ( 2,3,5 ))),0) AS count_waiting
              , IFNULL(SUM(IF(b.id_status NOT IN ( 1,2,3,5 ))),0) AS count_damaged
           FROM book_records b
           JOIN book_class c
             ON c.id_book = p.id_book
            AND c.class_desc = 'NOVEL'
          WHERE b.id_status IS NOT NULL
       ) t
 ORDER BY s.seq
```

---

(I don't see how your query runs, since it references `k.id_book` but there is no `k` row source. I'm going to assume that this really should be c.id_book; I don't see any join conditions between b and c and I don't think you mean to do a CROSS JOIN. I'm going to assume a one to many relationship between b and c, a book_record can have zero, one or more book_class, but you are only interested in book_record of a particular class. It also looks like you mean for each query to perform a GROUP BY to get a count of each status...)

Also, best practice is to qualify all column references in a query that references more than one row source.

To get the resultset you are returning, I'd do something like this, as a single pass through the table:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN b.id_status IN ( 1 ) THEN 'AVAILABLE'
            WHEN b.id_status IN ( 2,3,5 ) THEN 'WAITING'
            ELSE 'DAMAGED' // any non-NULL status that is not 1,2,3,5
       END AS status
     , COUNT(b.id_status) AS BIL
  FROM book_records b
  JOIN book_class c
    ON c.id_book = p.id_book
   AND c.class_desc = 'NOVEL'
 WHERE b.id_status IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY status
```

If id_status is guaranteed to be NOT NULL, you can omit that WHERE clause.

(It goes without saying that appropriate index on book_class, either with a leading column of `id_book` and including `book_class`, or possibly `on (book_class, id_book)`, would speed up the join operation. I'm assuming here that id_book is already a unique index on `book_record`. Ideally, there would be covering index `ON book_records (id_book,id_status)` as well.)

To get the same resultset you are returning is a little more work (to guaranteed three rows, and zero counts), but it should still be more efficient than running three queries:

```
SELECT s.status AS STATUS
     , IFNULL(t.BIL,0) AS BIL
  FROM ( SELECT 'AVAILABLE' AS status, 1 AS seq
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'WAITING', 2
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'DAMAGED', 3
       ) s
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT CASE WHEN b.id_status IN ( 1 ) THEN 'AVAILABLE'
                     WHEN b.id_status IN ( 2,3,5 ) THEN 'WAITING'
                     ELSE 'DAMAGED' // any non-NULL status that is not 1,2,3,5
                END AS status
              , COUNT(b.id_status) AS BIL
          FROM book_records b
          JOIN book_class c
            ON c.id_book = p.id_book
           AND c.class_desc = 'NOVEL'
         WHERE b.id_status IS NOT NULL
         GROUP BY status
       ) t
    ON t.status = s.status
 ORDER BY s.seq
```

Comment: TQ for your idea but I still not like the result I want. For your 1st query, if any status is null, the status will not be shown in the result and that is not like what I want it to be. Same like your 2nd query. I want the result show like what I show above.

Comment: @user3106393: yeah, I recognize that now, not getting the zero counts, I modified that query to guarantee three rows returned, with zero counts.

Comment: for this part:                                                           **FROM ( SELECT 'AVAILABLE' AS status, 1 AS seq
UNION ALL
SELECT 'WAITING', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DAMAGED', 3
) s'**                                                                  can u explain to me about this part? What is the meaning for 1 @ 2 @ 3? I not really understand

Comment: @user3106393: That inline view (aliased as s) returns exactly three rows, the "status" strings you want returned. The `seq` column 1,2,3 is included just so we can reference it in the `ORDER BY` (without an ORDER BY we aren't guaranteed the order the rows are returned.) We could use an expression in the ORDER BY to derive the sequence, I think it's just easier to use a simple column. Of course, we could get an equivalent result by ordering on the third character of the "status" strings (would be 'A','I' and 'M') with an `ORDER BY SUBSTR(s.status,3,1)`, but I prefer using the `seq` digit.

Comment: I try your query. No error but also no result appear.

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all`.  `union` removes duplicates which is unnecessary overhead:

```
SELECT 'AVAILABLE' AS STATUS, count(id_status) as BIL
FROM 
book_records AS b, book_class AS c
WHERE p.id_book = k.id_book AND id_status IN ( 1 ) AND class_desc =  'NOVEL'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'WAITING' AS STATUS, count(id_status) as BIL
FROM 
book_records AS b, book_class AS c
WHERE p.id_book = k.id_book AND id_status IN ( 2,3,5 ) AND class_desc =  'NOVEL'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DAMAGED' AS STATUS, count(id_status) as BIL
FROM 
book_records AS b, book_class AS c
WHERE p.id_book = k.id_book AND id_status NOT IN ( 1,2,3,5 ) AND class_desc =  'NOVEL';
```

NOTE:  I have left the query mistakes (such as the mismatching aliases) in the query on purpose.  This is the original query as posted.  I assume this is an artifact of translating the query identifiers from another language into English.

EDIT:

You don't need `union` at all for this query.  Instead:

```
select (case when id_status in ( 1 ) then 'Available'
             when id_status in (2, 3, 5) then 'Waiting'
             else 'Damaged'
         end),
        count(*) as cnt
from book_records br join
     book_class bc
     on br.id_book = pc.id_book 
where bc.class_desc = 'NOVEL'
group by (case when id_status in ( 1 ) then 'Available'
               when id_status in (2, 3, 5) then 'Waiting'
               else 'Damaged'
         end);
```

This query will run faster with an index on `book_class(class_desc, id_book)` and `book_records(id_book)`.

Comment: but whats the use of duplicate records..! I think it depends upon the requirement **union** or **union all** required.. !

Comment: The result still the same. I mean it load to slow. It take about 18.1814 second to load the result but what I want is it load faster than that. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @user3106393 . . . What you are calling "load" time is dominated by the time to run the query.  The result set has only three rows, so volume of data is not a consideration.  You need to speed up the query.

Comment: Yes, I know. I want to speed up my query but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you don't need a `UNION` for what you're doing. You can do that all in a single `SELECT` with a `CASE`. You also need to properly group the aggregate function:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN id_status = 1 THEN 'AVAILABLE'
        WHEN id_status IN (2, 3, 5) THEN 'WAITING'
        ELSE 'DAMAGED'
    END AS status, count(id_status) as BIL
    FROM book_records b
    LEFT JOIN book_class c ON b.id_book = c.id_book 
    WHERE c.class_desc = 'NOVEL'
    GROUP BY status;
```

Comment: I already try like this but when any of the status result to 0, it will not show in table. I want all 3 status show in table even the result is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE INDEX br_idx ON book_records (id_book, id_status);

CREATE INDEX bc_idx ON book_class (id_book, class_desc);
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to tell me. Can you explain please?

Comment: You can rewrite the queries in more than one way, as others have suggested. But, without an INDEX for the relevant fields, none of them will make it go faster.

Also, include b or c with id_book and id_status. For example, b.id_book, b.id_status and c.class_desc.

Comment: Having an INDEX will tell the query to look in the index (extremely fast), rather than scan (very slow) the two tables.

Comment: Looking at your query, it looks like you're using id_book and id_status from table book_records. This is for the first CREATE INDEX.

And you're using id_book and class_desc from table book_class, hence, the second CREATE INDEX.

Comment: Run the 2 CREATE INDEX command above, and re-run your query. It should go much faster.